# Looking up GPS coordinates for United States counties

Tags: python, actionscript-3, parsing, gps

I'm currently working on a small project to try to visualize 2012 election results based on population density, per county. I'm parsing relevant data in Python, then a colleague of mine is using AS3 to visualize the data.

What was once just a scale-able bar graph, is soon to become a visualization on the map of the United States. It would be very useful to find GPS coordinate data per county. I've found TIGER data and shapefiles, but I assume there has got to be some collection of data that simplifies position to GPS coordinates.

Does anyone know where I can find this data? Either downloadable or accessed via a free-to-use API?

Comment: [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) may meet your requirement.  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. Census Bureau has loads of API's and publicly available data:

http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/index.html

http://www.census.gov/developers/

http://www.census.gov/developers/data/

I'm not sure if they provide latitude and longitude, but it's a good place to start.